# Install Yarn Ubuntu 16.04 (Linux Mint 18.1)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, yarnpkg

I have a new installation of Linux Mint 18.1 with Ubuntu 16.04.
I have installed Node 6.10.0.

When doing the command that indicates the documentation of Yarn:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

It says "could not find yarn package"

I must do something else, because in the documentation I do not see anything about it.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 175, accepted):

On Ubuntu Linux, you can install Yarn via Debian package repository. You will first need to configure the repository:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

Then you can simply:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

More information [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#linux-tab)

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood and thought that I did not have to take that step with 16.04.

Comment: Note: Ubuntu 17.04 comes with cmdtest installed by default. If you’re getting errors from installing yarn, you may want to run sudo apt remove cmdtest first. Refer to this for more information.

Comment: @vulcan_hacker yes and Node.js is already installed. I though of re-installing it. It always gives me issues, Fact is Node.js supports Linux Mint 17.2 not 18. 

I did follow all those instruction, still yarn does not work

Comment: This installation will install default node version from it's apt repository, which will break existing nodejs installation, if it's installed in some other way, like nvm, for example

Comment: From my perspective it would be nice if Yarn were part of the ubuntu distribution

Comment: @ffejrekaburb maybe one day it will be

Answer (score 48):

I was unable to install Yarn on Ubuntu 16.04 using the accepted answer but found it easy with npm:

`npm install -g yarn`

Then check install / version with

`yarn --version`

Comment: npm WARN deprecated yarnpkg@0.15.1: Please use the `yarn` package instead of `yarnpkg`

Comment: Thanks @qräbnö, adjusted

Comment: You should mention that it is recommended to use the Linux distro package distribution system as it is optimised for it !

Comment: This answer is better, because installing yarn, breaks installation of nodejs, if it was not installed by apt repository as well...

Answer (score 5):

See on [Installation | Yarn | Linux tab](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#linux-tab)

There are instructions for several linux distributions

Comment: I get `minified react error#96` in my browser console here :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are more details about the [official install instruction](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#linux-tab).

1. `apt-key` command gets the public authentication key for software integration check.
2. `deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main` is the Ubuntu repository containing `yarn`. Look at OP's screenshot, the top 10 lines list existing repositories to search for packages, but there is no yarn's one. So we need to add the repository by creating file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list`.
3. After the above two steps, issue `apt`/`apt-get` command to add `yarn` like usual Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using `&&`. I get the same error when running `sudo apt-get update`, which prevents terminal from running `sudo apt-get install yarn`.   I was able to successfully install yarn on Ubuntu 16.04 by running these commands separately (without using `&&`)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu or Linux you can install yarn using terminal ,But before installing You will first need to configure the repository, for that run the below commands

```
sudo apt install curl

curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

after setting up the repository you can simply install yarn using below command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

Once the installation gets completed you can check the version using following command

```
yarn --version
```

[for more details go to yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable)